# How to prove LP integral solution when total unimodularity fails?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, binary-programming, integrality-gap

I have a problem that I managed to write as a binary integer linear program. As a natural first step, I relaxed the integrality constraint to solve a regular LP. To my surprise, the solutions where all integral (either $0$ or $1$).

I then ran some simulations on random instances of my problem and, to my surprise, all were integral.

I started looking into the constraint matrix to try to prove it is totally unimodular, but managed to find a counterexample [An instance whose constraint matrix is **not** totally unimodular].

So I am left puzzled. I've been running simulations for the past two days on random instances of the problem in hope to find a counterexample [Where the solution of the LP are non integral] to no avail.

What is the next step after total unimodularity that you can explore to prove that the solution of an LP formulation is integral?

Comment: To my knowledge, the literature states that the linear program $\max\{c^Tx:Ax\leqslant b, x\geqslant0\}$ has an integral optimal solution for all integer vectors $b$ for which it has a finite optimal value if and only if $A$ is totally unimodular. Have you tried varying the RHS?

Comment: @Math1000 My RHS ($b$) is actually constant for all instances [and integral either $0,1,$ or $-1$]. So it is mainly the matrix A that I've been changing based on the different instances.

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com may be a better home for this question.

Comment: Just to be clear, the instance that was not TUM still coughed up an integral solution?

Comment: @prubin Yes, exactly

Comment: Are you maximizing a linear function over a constraint set whose extreme points all have integer coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

When TUM fails, you try a weaker notion called Total Dual Integrality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_dual_integrality)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).